# Bootcamp - safety of OSX partition

Tags: bootcamp

I use OSX and Windows 7 on my MBA. I have an access to OSX partition on Windows 7. I was wondering... is it safe? I mean, could OSX partition be destroyed by some kind of virus? Is there any way to disable that partition in Windows 7, making it unaccessible for any program, virus, etc. ?

Comment: In General it is no Problem Windows can just read from your Macs Disk but not write so Viruses also can't do anything evil to your Mac but if you install some third party Application which emabled your Windows to write to the Mac Disk it looks different. if you want get totally rid of acces to your MacDrive on you Windows remove the HFS+ driver which Bootcamp installed onto your Windows the your Windows doesn't eaven know that there is a MacDrive.

Answer (score 1):

When you are booted to OS X, Open the security & privacy preferences pane and choose the File Vault tab. Then turn on File Vault 2. This will encrypt your entire OS X partition, making the data unreadable when not logged into a OS X user account.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4790